# Why can't one instruction include two memory references in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm a beginner in assembly language. I have learned that the below instruction is invalid because it cannot have both source and destination be memory references. I want to know the reason.

```
movl (%eax) (%ebx)
```

Comment: Accessing memory requires a memory address accessing cycle (assert read request, data available, read data, unassert read). An instruction such as `movl (%eax) (%ebx)` would require sequencing two memory access cycles, making the instruction sequencing architecture of the CPU more complex for little pay-back.

Comment: duplicate: [Why isn't movl from memory to memory allowed?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33794169)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instruction sets require that bit patterns be designed to encode the instructions.   One could have bit patterns for every conceivable instruction, but then the processor would not be practical to construct.  So processor designers limit the variety (and consequently often the style) of instructions to make processor construction easier.

A common theme in processor design is that instructions operate on *one* register and *one* memory location. Two operands means this style can do load memory to register, store register to memory, and a variety of common binary operations such as add memory to register, compare register to memory, etc. This theme works so well in practice that there is little need for instructions that work on multiple memory locations, and its regularity makes the "central" processing part of the CPU easier to implement.  The "movl" instruction you mention fits this theme, thus, only one memory operand.

So the real answer is that the payoff for having such an instruction doesn't justify the engineering.

Most processor designs have now been around for 20+ years, and now transistors are relatively cheap.  As a consequence, the instruction sets for virtually all these machines has gotten more complex, often including *some* instructions that refer to multiple memory operands. But these instructions are the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Good point that it's an instruction-encoding limitation more than anything.  x86 has memory-to-memory instructions, but with at most one *explicit* memory operand using a full addressing mode.  e.g. `push [ebx + ecx]`, or `movsb`.  This would be a better answer if you pointed out that even the memory/memory instructions that exist don't have two explicit addressing modes, so the decoders only ever need to handle one at once.

Comment: Fun fact: VAX uses 2-operand instructions with an arbitrary addressing mode for each operand.  But as I understand it, VAX was heavily microcoded internally, so it got quite low IPC and/or didn't clock very high.

Comment: @PeterCordes: The x86 converts most of its complex instructions into what amounts to a stream of micro instructions.   If the VAX designers had as many transistors as Intel has now, I suspect its performance would be pretty good.   The real problem with the VAX instruction set was that if you stick to the RISC part of it (load, compare, jump),you get programs that are just as effective as if you used the CISC part to the hilt, so there wasn't much point to keeping the CISC stuff.  The other point was VAX insruction set was designed for people to write; these days, compilers do all the work.

Comment: I might be mis-remembering, but I think VAX's instruction-encoding was slightly more bulky than x86 (even for reg-reg or reg/mem).  Also, it would probably be harder to build efficient decoders, unless you just give up on supporting giant instructions efficiently.  (e.g. some x86 CPUs stall on instructions with more than 3 prefixes, instead of decoding in parallel.  I guess with a modern transistor budget, you might build a VAX like that, where fast decoding is only possible for a limited subset and compilers would just use that..)

Comment: @IraBaxter, so can 'imul' takes both memory operands?

Comment: @amjad:  No.  But you shouldn't ask me, you should consult the Intel instruction set reference documents: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-manual.pdf

Answer (score 4):

There's no real *reason* - it's just the way the Intel instruction set happens to be defined.  There *are* a couple of Intel instructions that *do* take two memory references, though: `movs`, for example.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `movs` might even be the legal version of what the OP was trying to accomplish. It is much more expensive than doing a load and store though.

Answer (score -2):

Use [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) to move data in memory is faster then cpu.

Comment: That's not really true in modern x86 systems; the memory controllers are integrated into the CPU package, and there isn't any standard DMA blit engine in mainstream x86 platforms, let alone one on chip.  Also, other than very large copies, it's common for data to be hot in cache. where CPU cores can access it faster than anything else.  And most importantly, this in no way answers the question about instruction-set design.  8086 / 8088 wasn't designed to be used with a DMA memcpy engine, and it *does* have `rep movs` for mem-mem copies.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.